# Prove that function $g(n)=\zeta^{5n}$ is surjective from $\mathbb Z$ to the set of roots of unity

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

I have this math problem, that I'm kind of stuck on.

> $\mu_{102} = \{ z \in \mathbb{C}: z^{102} = 1\}$
>
> Let $\zeta = e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{102}}.$  Define $g : \mathbb{Z} \to
>  \mu_{102}$ with the formula $g(n)= \zeta^{5n}$ for $ n \in
>  \mathbb{Z}$.  Show that $g$ is surjective.

I know that to prove a function is surjective I have to let $y\in \mu_{102}$ and find $x\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(x) = y$. However, I'm not sure how to apply this to the given function.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: 1) $\zeta$ generates $\mu_{102}$, so all you have to do is to find $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(x) = \zeta$.

2) That means you want $\zeta^{5n} = \zeta$. If you write down what that means in terms of the exponents of $e$, you should be able to get a congruence that you can solve.

Comment: So I'll have $e^{\frac{10n\pi i}{102}} = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{102}}$?

Comment: Yes, that's right. So what does that tell you about the relationship between $10n$ and $2$?

Comment: I'm still not clear as to why that is important to find out whether the given function is surjective or not.

Comment: If you find an $n$ such that $\zeta^{5n} = \zeta$, then the function is surjective, since any element of $\mu_{102}$ is $\zeta^k$ for some $k$, and then $f(k) = \zeta^{5nk} = (\zeta^{5n})^k = \zeta^k$.

Comment: So, how will the relationship between $10n$ and $2$, help me?

Comment: You want $e^{\frac{10n\pi i}{102}} = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{102}}$. For this to hold, what must be true of the exponents? (Recall that $e^{2\pi i} = 1$).

Answer (score 0):

If you take $n=45k$, $g(41k)=\zeta^{205k}=\zeta^{(204+1)k}=\zeta^k $.